# SSRS filter parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I have "Country" filter dropdown list in ssrs report. This contains all countries and it is a multiselect dropdownlist. If user selects "All" the reports sends all country names comma separated to a storedprocedure where I have the query to display data. In stored procedure i split the values and compare the data. No issues so far. Now what I want is, If user selects "All", i don't need to pass all comma separated values to SP, instead pass null. So in my sp i don't have to split or join the tables. The problem is identifying whether the user has selected the "All" check box in the report criteria.Is there a way to find this whether the "All" is selected?

the country is dynamic, so i don't have a lookup value to count all countries. 
Parameters!Country.Count == 10 -- I can't do that because I don't know the 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate dataset where you count the number countries .

```
Select count(countryName) as cntCountry from yourTable
```

Now you can compare this field cntCountry with the Parameters!Country.Count

```
Fields!cntCountry.Value==Parameters!Country.Count
```

or you can use [CountRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function where in you pass the dataset

```
Parameters!Country.Count=CountRows(dataset1)
```

Edit : If the above one doesn't work

```
   Parameters!Country.Count=CountRows()
```

Why don't you create a field in your dataset which will be storing the number of rows .while creating a dataset just get the row_number in your sql query and then match this value with  `Parameters!Country.Count`

Comment: Thanks Praveen, unortunately CountRows(dataset1) does not work : the error message is : @Country includes an aggregate or lookup function. Aggregate and lookup functions cannot be used in query parameters. The whole point here is tune up the performance. As you said, I can get the country count from database but, this is Ok for small amout of data. But I may have some other datasets which will have more rows. Is there any other way to do this please?